# Difficulty getting the desired result in Oracle

Tags: aggregate, row-number, rownum

I have 2 tables in my Oracle DB with the following structure and data:

Table 1: Employees

| Emp_ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| E1 | A |
| E2 | B |
| E3 | C |

Table 2: Dependants (employees children with name and birth dates)

| Emp_ID | Depdt_ID | Depdt_name | Depdt_dob |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E1 | D1 | Aa | 2020-12-31 |
| E1 | D2 | Ab | 2012-07-14 |
| E2 | D3 | Ba | 2017-01-30 |
| E2 | D4 | Bb | 2001-03-21 |
| E2 | D5 | Bc | 2005-12-06 |
| E2 | D6 | Bd | 2012-01-14 |
| E3 | D7 | Ca | 1999-05-20 |
| E1 | D8 | Ac | 2021-07-28 |

I need the list of workers and for each of them the name and birth date of their youngest child:
Result needed:

| Emp_ID | Depdt_name | Depdt_dob |
| --- | --- | --- |
| E2 | Ba | 2017-01-30 |
| E3 | Ca | 1999-05-20 |
| E1 | Ac | 2021-07-28 |

How can I achieve this result in Oracle?

Rownum in a subquery, but I still don't understand the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
   Emp_id,
   Depdt_name,
   Depdt_dob,
   RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Emp_ID ORDER BY Depdt_dob DESC) AS dpdt_age_rank
FROM Employees AS e
LEFT JOIN Dependant AS d
ON e.Emp_ID = d.Emp_ID
WHERE dpdt_age_rank = 1
```

This will rank all dependants, ordered by date of birth from youngest to oldest and partitioned per employee id and filter only for the youngest, even if there are any twins. Note that if you use ROW_NUMBER() instead of RANK() you would lose any twins cause it does not tie results.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I tried running the the query and it looks like Oracle doesn't recognize the alias of that last column. I get the following error message:


ORA-00904: "DPDT_AGE_RANK" : identificateur non valide
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Erreur à la ligne 3, colonne 7

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a solution to my question thanks to @arthurq's answer above.

Here is the final form of the query:

```
WITH Youngest_Child AS (
SELECT
   e.Emp_id,
   e.name,
   d.Depdt_name,
   d.Depdt_dob,
   RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY e.Emp_ID ORDER BY d.Depdt_dob DESC) AS dpdt_age_rank
FROM Employees AS e
LEFT JOIN Dependant AS d
ON e.Emp_ID = d.Emp_ID
)
SELECT Emp_id, name, Depdt_name, Depdt_dob
FROM Youngest_Child 
WHERE dpdt_age_rank = 1
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice! Well done